# .gitignore does not work - file is still being tracked

Tags: git, gitignore

I've a `.gitignore` file at the root of my repo. The `.gitignore` file has the following pattern to exclude the compiled Python files and that is the only line in the file.

```
*.pyc
```

Now when i do the following at the root of the repo.

```
git init
git add . 
git status
```

It shows that it still tracks the `.pyc` file and tries to add it as new file. See output below.

System info: Windows 7, cygwin

Note: This issue is CLEARLY not about the ignored file being already tracked. I also tried both DOS- and Unix-style line endings on the `.gitignore` file.

`git status` gives:

```
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .gitignore
#   new file:   feedapp/__init__.py
#   new file:   feedapp/appconfig.py
#   new file:   feedapp/appconfig.pyc
```

How do I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: What is the output from 'git status'? That'll help a lot.

Comment: was the .gitignore file in place and populated before your git add .?

Comment: Yes it was there before even the git init

Comment: What do you get from `git rm --cached -r . ; git add . ; git status`

Comment: Do you have any whitespace at the end of the line containing `*.pyc` in your `.gitignore` file? I've just done a little test and it seems to be significant.

Comment: matt: you are right. it had something to do with line ending.

Comment: refer to below post, it works fine to me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring

Answer (score 143):

`.gitignore` only applies to **untracked** files. If you are tracking a `.pyc` then `.gitignore` won't apply. Remove the `.pyc` with `git rm` and next time you do a `git status` it (and any others) won't show up in the list of untracked file and nor will it  be automatically added.

---

Otherwise if you need to ignore a file already under version control, update the index to ignore changes to files already under version control:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <files>
```

For more information please see [*git-update-index(1) Manual Page*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html), the [related answer to *.gitignore file not ignoring*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11366713/367456) and the [related answer to question (*GIT: Ignoring Version-Controlled Files*)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4633776/367456).

Comment: These files are not tracked yet....

Comment: According to your 'git status' output, they are.

Comment: What you mean they are tracked? I see that they are 'new file'

Comment: @Gnu Engineer, They are tracked. They are in the index, a staging area created by `git add`. Whether they were placed there before `.gitignore` was created or not is unknowable.

Comment: Just to be clear, if `appconfig.pyc` wasn't already in the index from an earlier `git add`, `git add .` should have ignored it.

Comment: ikegami: Problem is resolved. It seems to due to with the format of the line ending. I had created the .gitignore with an editor and later recreated via echo. I did a d2u now and it worked it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks! Did not know of the git update-index - really useful!

Answer (score 35):

`man gitignore`:

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally **untracked files** that git should ignore. Note that all the gitignore files really concern only files that are not already tracked by git

`git rm file` will stop tracking them. I can't find a way to remove all ignored files from the repo.

---

As you point out, the files don't appear to already exist in the repo. In that case, your `git`'s behaviour matches neither the documentation or the behaviour of mine, and I can't help you.

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
/home/ikegami/foo
$ mkdir feedapp
$ touch feedapp/__init__.py
$ touch feedapp/appconfig.py
$ touch feedapp/appconfig.pyc
$ echo '*.pyc' > .gitignore
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ikegami/foo/.git/
$ git add .
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   .gitignore
#       new file:   feedapp/__init__.py
#       new file:   feedapp/appconfig.py
#
$
```

---

Perhaps you did

```
git init
git add .
echo '*.pmc' >> .gitignore
git init
git add .
```

in which case you can fix the problem using

```
git rm --cached -r .
git add .
```

Comment: My understanding is that the git is not tracking any files in repo yet. I'm trying to do an initial commit ignoring the *.pyc files.

Comment: ikegami: I've the same conclusion as yours. All along i've done this several times before. I suspect this has something to do with cygwin but yet this is a very simple pattern that it has to support....

Comment: @Gnu Engineer, I use git over cygwin at home. I'll try it there later. For now, I added a possible cause and solution to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: be cautioned when using `git rm --cached -r .` it actually removes everything  on current directory

Answer (score 17):

I had the exact same problem. I found out that running `"someText" > .gitignore` made a file with a weird encoding. I changed it to UTF-8, then all worked fine.

Comment: Also make sure there is no BOM! (Byte order mark)

Answer (score 6):

I have had exactly the same problem--even if I prepare a .gitignore file before the first time I add anything.
And I found the problem was in the blank space in my ignore file.
DO NOT add any white space in your ignore file and try again. I think everything will just work fine. 
Good luck

Answer (score 5):

Check the line endings on your .gitignore file. In an OS X repo, mine was using CR line endings. Everything worked again after switching over to LFs.

```
perl -p -e 's/\r/\n/g'  < .gitignore > .gitignore-new
mv .gitignore-new .gitignore
```

Console jockeys will likely want to use `sed` instead.

Background: I had copied my working copy from a Windows repository after a power failure.

Comment: Same for me. If you are using `vim`, do `:set ff=unix`. For some reason it was set to `mac`.