# gitignore settings included in commit

Tags: git, commit, gitignore

I'm trying to commit the right files in git, but having problems configuring my gitignore properly. I followed the instructions [here](http://www.gyford.com/phil/writing/2010/09/29/django-environment.php) to create the gitignore file (django project):

```
# File types #
##############
*.pyc
*.swo
*.swp
*.swn

# Directories #
###############
logs/

# Specific files #
##################
projectname/settings.py

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
ehthumbs.db
Icon
Thumbs.db
*~
```

The problem is that settings.py is getting included in the commit:

```
Admin$ git add .
Admin$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   projectname/settings.py
```

How can I ignore settings in my gitignore?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.gitignore file not ignoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you already have `settings.py` under version control by git. In this case git will continue to track the file - no matter what you write in `.gitignore`.

You have to explicitly tell git to forget about `settings.py`:

1. Add it to `.gitignore` (As you did)
2. Remove the file from git without deleting the file: `git rm --cached projectname/settings.py`
3. Commit the change: `git commit -m "remove settings.py"`

Afterwards git will ignore the file. But be aware that versions which are already commited will stay in your repository.

Comment: Ok well what should I do to fix it so that the settings isn't included in the future?

Comment: This is probably the correct answer, people often misunderstand this. **If the file is already versioned git will keep tracking it even if there is a match for it on .gitignore; you have to manually remove it, and then, now, git will ignore it.**

Comment: @talles, there is another way, without removing it ... `git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file`

Comment: If you want to remove the file in a commit but not in the current directory: `cp file tmp; git rm file; git commit ...; mv tmp file` is the hard way :-) and the easy way is `git rm --cached file`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `/` before your directory

```
# Specific files #
##################
/projectname/settings.py
```

For any further information,

```
$ mkdir git_test
$ cd git_test/
~/git_test $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/linux/git_test/.git/
~/git_test $ touch .gitignore
~/git_test $ vim .gitignore
~/git_test $ cat .gitignore 
/aa/aa.py

~/git_test $ mkdir aa
~/git_test $ touch aa/aa.py
~/git_test $ 
~/git_test $ 
~/git_test $ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

If you still facing the same issue:

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately it is still being included in the commit. Any ideas about how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508445/how-to-ignore-existing-committed-files-in-git

Answer (score 0):

For a file that is already versioned, the [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) suggests using `git update-index --assume-unchanged projectname/settings.py`, rather than .gitignore.